# Is Spark Default Parallelism given priority over Input Split?

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark, the number of partitions are equal to input splits. I have a 5MB file, when I read it as RDD and default parallelism set to 2, then I see number of partitions as 2, but there will be 1 input split. What is the precedence here, is it InputSplit given priority over Default Parallelism?

Answer (score 0):

The number of partitions of a Spark RDD defaults to [`spark.default.parallelism`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/configuration.html#execution-behavior).

([InputSplit](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputSplit.html) is an Hadoop concept, not used by Spark).